# jQuery can't set input value after ajax submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have AJAX code which submits form. It works fine, but the problem is I can't set inputs value on success. This is the HTML:

```
        <div id="chat_box" hidden="true">
            <div id="chat_box_head"></div>
            <div id="chat_box_body">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                @foreach($conv as $c)
                <li>
                    <img src="{{$c->user->image}}" style="height: 30px">
                    {{$c->message}}
                </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>    
                <form id="chatForm" method="post" action="siusti-zinute">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                    <input type="text" id="inputMessage" name="message">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is AJAX:

```
  $('#chatForm').submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      url: 'siusti-zinute',
      type: 'post',
      data: $('#chatForm').serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function( _response ){
        $("#inputMessage").val(''); // THIS IS NOT WORKING.
        $('#chat_box_body').animate({scrollTop: $('#chat_box_body').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500); // THIS ALSO NOT WORKING
      },
      error: function( _response ){
          // Handle error
      }
  });
});
```

This `$("#inputMessage").val(''); // THIS IS NOT WORKING.` Not working in success

Comment: Have you checked with a `console.log()` if its going inside the `success` handler function?

Comment: Does your page on which you post, return anything?

Comment: @Vandesh I just checked and it's not working :/

Comment: Check whether is your ajax call is working or not?

Comment: Nothing works inside success function

Comment: Here's a couple of things you can do - Check if it's going in the `error` function. If yes, what is the error that you get. Also, check using Postman Extension in Chrome if the post call is working correctly or if you are missing something.

Comment: problem might be ID is duplicate? Try change handle to class or data instead of ID if can be duplicate.

Comment: @Vandesh Yes the error function is working. How to check what error it is ?

Comment: @feknuolis you can check status code or xhr. Look at examples http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: add a `console.log(_response);` inside the error function and check what the object contains

Comment: `{readyState: 4, responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵    <meta …);↵      }↵  });↵});↵↵</script>↵↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}`

Comment: @daremachine Of course one can. Trying to help in the simplest and an intuitive manner :)

Comment: `return response()->json();` I forgot to add this to my controller. My bad. :/

Comment: Check if it's a valid JSON that you are returning

Comment: @Vandesh My eyes sorry. Bad nick :) feknuolis, you expect json from response but you send html source.

Comment: If it's an invalid JSON or an empty response, it shows status 200 OK, but results in a parseerror which calls the error function instead

Comment: Looks like @feknuolis solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you return anything on the page you post to, otherwise the success function might not work.

```
$data = array();
$data['result'] = true;
Echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 return response()->json();
```

I forgot to add this line in controller.